# React-Redux-Form save data to prop from onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am new react-redux and I am trying to save to props the value entered in from a react-redux-form textbox by using the onChange event which can be passed to another component

My code snippet for the textbox is

```
 <ListItemContent>
      <Control component={Textfield} model="somemodel" label="MyLabel"
        onChange={this.props}/>
 </ListItemContent>
```

How can I save this value and make this available to other components?

EDIT I have it partly working:

```
     <ListItemContent>
          <Control component={Textfield} model="somemodel" label="MyLabel"
            onBlur={this.onChangeOfValue}/>
     </ListItemContent>

      onChangeOfValue = (event) =>
      {
           this.setState({ newValueToPassAlong:   event.target.value}); //newValueToPassAlong is set in constructor
     };



  .....

   let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {newValueToGive: state.newValueToPassAlong} //This is undefined
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(form)
```

Further, my componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) is not being fired when the other component's state changes.

Comment: There's a lot that can go on in passing info with react and redux. Assuming you want to use redux to update the state of the input field and you plan to mapStateToProps in your other component, then you can review my example of a basic react-redux app that uses react-redux-form: https://github.com/Fallenstedt/redux_blog/blob/master/src/components/posts_new.js#L24

I would need more information from you regarding how you plan to pass this information to your other component before giving you a detailed answer.

Comment: We have two components - one is purely an input form which is where we need to do the onChange on one of the textboxes and the other is a supplementary form where need to pass in the value from this textbox. There is no submission of the form, and I am not too sure whether there is a way where I can access this value globally, perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// YOUR TEXTFIELD COMPONENT
import React, { Component } form 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import {passValueToOtherComponent} from '../actions/your-actions-index-file';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ListItemContent form 'list-item-content';

class TextField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      textFieldValue: '',
    }
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    var newValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({textFieldValue: newValue});
    //when input changes
    //call action to update global state...
    this.props.passValueToOtherComponent(this.state.textFieldValue)
  }

  render() {
    <form>
    <ListItemContent>
         <Control component={Textfield} model="somemodel" label="MyLabel"
           onChange={this.onInputChange} value={this.state.textFieldValue}/>
    </ListItemContent>
    </form>
  }
}

//ReduxForm wrapper
const wrappedReduxForm = connect(null, {passValueToOtherComponent})(TextField)

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'TextField'
})(TextField)


// actions/your-actions-index-file.js
//create an action which will call to update global state
export const NEW_VALUE = "NEW_VALUE"

export function passValueToOtherComponent(value) {
    return {
    type: CREATE_POST,
    payload: value,
  }
}


//YOUR NewValue Reducer
//reducer_new_value.js
//create reducer which will accept payload data
import {NEW_VALUE} from '../actions/your-actions-index-file';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  valueToPass: null
};

export default function (state = [], action) {
  console.log('Action...' action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case NEW_VALUE:
      return { ...state, valueToPass: action.payload.data}
      break;
    default:

  }
}

//Your Root Reducer
//Because you may have lots of state to manage, a rootReducer is awesome in managing it all
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import NewValueReducer from './reducer_new_value';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // state: (state = {}) => state
  value: NewValueReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;



//finally pass this desired value to your desired Component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class OtherComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value= {this.props.texFieldValue}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { textFieldValue: state.value.valueToPass }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OtherComponent);
```

This is something I just typed out. Not sure if it will work, but it covers actions, reducers, and updating values from one component to anohter. Of course, this is a crazy way to do it using react redux. I'm not sure how efficient it would be to call this action on every input change. You might be better off passing the current value of state as a prop to your desired component.

If you have some more questions, I'd be happy to help or point you to some other resources.

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering whether as the value is not going away apart from being shared between two components does it need to go through reducers? Could the state simply be updated without too much scripting.  Further the textbox is already part of a form and is not a component on its own and the component has a connect

Comment: Yeah it can happen. Let me whip up a codepen here to demonstrate it....

Comment: Thanks that would be most helpful

Comment: I am just looking through your code now am I home and have my laptop open, and I am not clear why I need to do this in the import for the react component that is export the value to the other component. //ReduxForm wrapper
const wrappedReduxForm = connect(null, {passValueToOtherComponent})(TextField)

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'TextField'
})(TextField) -- I take it this would be part of the form component and that reduxForm is the name of the react component

Comment: I have played around with this and I have it partly working, but I am still not to get value from one component to the other. See edit